# Unable to send devise password as json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise for User table. In the api method I want to send my User record along with the password field as json. My code for that is:

```
users = User.where(status: "active")
```

Here in users I get all the fields including encrypted_password.
But when I try to send this data with:

```
render json: { users: users }
```

the devise columns doesn't appear in the result except email.

How can I get password too in the result?

Comment: Why do you want to give out user's password in json? That will easily have security problems.

Comment: @Yang, I have a requirement to send password also, so that on every login request won't get sent to the server for validating user credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise overrides the `serializable_hash` method to expose only accessible attributes.

Override `as_json` method in User class

```
def as_json(options = {})
  options[:methods] ||= []
  options[:methods] << :encrypted_password
  super options
end
```

or use

```
user.to_json(methods: [:encrypted_password])
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much  for your help Jaehyun Shin :)